# Alternative to Multiple Inheritance to Extend Library

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I'm currently trying to extend [WPILib](https://docs.wpilib.org/en/stable/). Unfortunately I would need multiple inheritance.

I've drawn a uml diagram of the problem (forgive me my crappy handwriting)
[image]

As you can see with the red arrows I would need to extend from two classes.

I can't change any thing inside the WPI box and the `requires` method from `ICommand` needs some functions from `CommandBase` so I can't make it default in `ICommand`.

How can I solve this?

If you want to try some thing out here's [my github repo](https://github.com/6417/FridoWPI/tree/feature/Command).

Comment: it is not possible to have multiple inheritance in Java. If Inheritance doesn't work, try using Composition

Comment: If I use Composition would I still be able to use `SequentialCommandGroup` as a `WPI.Command`?

Comment: have you tried? the only thing I'm certain about: multiple inheritance won't work in Java (unless we're talking about interfaces)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Composition? And which classes should I compose?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: You show `SequentialCommandGroup` extending `CommandBase` via two routes. What exactly are the semantics you want from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to have your custom classes (SequentialCommandGroup, ParallelCommandGroup) to extend from library classes, but also to have your own implementation for that "Command" part.

You cannot have multiple inheritance in Java of course, but I think you could utilize [Proxy pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-proxy-pattern) here.

Your classes would still inherit from Library classes, but the implementation of ICommand interface could be delegated to Command object.

Example:

```
public class MyParallelCommandGroup extends ParallelCommandGroup implements ICommand {

    private Command commandProxy;
    
    public MyParallelCommandGroup() {
        // instantiate commandProxy here, or inject it as constructor param
    }
    
    @Override
    public void requires() {
        commandProxy.requires();
    }
    
}
```

You could even extract whole Command class to an interface and implement it in your proxy class. I'm not sure whether this covers your use-case, but maybe it will help you to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Interface` because `java is not supports Multiple Inheritance`. Interfaces are abstract types that specify behaviors for classes to implement. Because they are abstract, interfaces do not contain detailed instructions for their behaviors. Instead, the classes provide concrete implementations of interface behaviors.

***Interfaces have many defining characteristics:***

- Unlike classes, you don't instantiate interfaces. Instead, classes
  implement interfaces
- Interfaces contain only public constant definitions and method headers
- Interfaces can only extend other interfaces, not classes
- Interfaces can extend multiple interfaces, and classes can implement
  multiple interfaces

[Read more about Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html)